# Processing a list whilst using threading

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, signals, cpu

My code has a loop which checks a list and if there are items in the list it will process them and remove them from the list. The items are continuously inserted into the list by another thread.

Here is the code:

```
while True:
    for item in list:
        Process(item)
        Remove(item)
```

**Problem 1:**

What I have above works but the problem is that it is very intensive on the cpu.
I can put something like 'time.sleep' in the code but this program needs to process the items in the list immediately without any delay. How do I make it less intensive on the cpu (remember that I am concurrently running another thread).

**Problem 2**:

I want to stop the loop from running when the list is empty and continue to process when something is added to the list. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: i don't understand, can you describe the problem?

Comment: you can use timeout function, if I understand what you mean.

Comment: i just put problem tip